# Sed parameter getting replaced with backslashes

Tags: regex, sed

I want to run search and replace and I am trying the following command:

```
sed -i "s/\$enviro ?=.*[^;]/ = 1;/g" constants.php
```

For some reason when I try and run this is turns into:

```
sed -i "s/\$enviro\ \?=.\*\[\^\;\]/\ =\ 1\;/g\" constants.php
```

This then gives errors:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 28: unknown option to `s'
```

I simply want to run the regex `\$enviro ?=.*[!;]` and replace it with `$enviro = 1;`.

Input - a large config file, one of the lines being:

```
       $enviro = 0;
```

Output - still large config file:

```
$enviro = 1;
```

Comment: here ? is treated literal. Also [!;] is matching one of this two characters, if you want to match character which is not ; then [^;]. Also missing single quotes (or double) in sed expression. I'll suggest entering input/output text line(s)

Comment: @josifoski how do I avoid the `?` being treated as a literal? I will swap the negation

Comment: using gnu sed with -r, then ? if needed will be as common standard

Comment: While not the problem, why not use single quotes (`'`) around the regex, instead of double quotes, to eliminate any expansion worries?

Comment: @bishop Looks to be working now :). `sed -ri 's/\$enviro ?=.*[;]/$enviro = 1;/g' constants.php`

Comment: self effort solution is always best, i'm glad it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this gnu sed

```
sed -i -r 's/(\$enviro *= *)[^;]*/\1 1/' file
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this sed command:

```
sed -i.bak 's/\(\$enviro *=\).*/\1 1;/' constants.php
```